# Limit behavior of $\sum_{x=0}^m\binom{n}{x}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

I am interested in sums of the form
$$A_n = \sum_{x=0}^m \binom{n}{x}.$$

When $m = n$ we clearly have $A_n = 2^n$. In the case where $m \neq n$, we have

$$A_n = 2^n - \binom{n}{m+1}{}_{2}F_{1}(1, m-n+1, m+2, -1),$$
where ${}_{2}F_{1}$ denotes the hypergeometric function.

What is the limiting behavior of $A_n$ for fixed $m$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$? Obviously we still have $A_n = \mathcal O(2^n)$, but can we say anything stronger than this (in terms of functions which are nicer than the hypergeometric function)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $A_n$ is a polynomial in the variable $n$ with the leading term $\frac{n^m}{m!}$. We also have a crude bound

$$ \binom{n}{m} \leq A_n \leq \binom{n+m}{m} $$

for non-negative integers $n$. The following post may also help:

- [Sum of 'the first k' binomial coefficients for fixed n](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17202/sum-of-the-first-k-binomial-coefficients-for-fixed-n)